# How to directly get object from Silverlight WCF RIA Domain Services

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf-ria-services, domainservices

I'm starting to use a Silverlight WCF RIA Domain Services and I have one question.

So far I was able to fill a DataGrid with data coming from my WCF. This is alright.

But I'd like to simply get a list of, let's say, all my users. Normally with the DataGrid I'd do:

```
CortexDomainContext oContext = new CortexDomainContext();

this.dataGrid1.ItemsSource = oContext.Users;
oContext.Load(oContext.GetUsersQuery());
```

But if I only want to get a List of the result, how must I do it?!

I tried:

```
List<User> oUsers = oContext.Users.ToList();
oContext.Load(oContext.GetUsersQuery());
```

But it didn't worked.

Everything is working alright but this question still remains in my mind...

Thanks a lot!

Comment: "But it didn't worked." -  be more specific....

Comment: It did not filled my list with any users at all. That is why it did not worked. The list remained empty.

Comment: and when you step through in a debugger, does the list contain anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DomainContext.Load` is asynchronous as any other web call in Silverlight, therefore you get the results either via a callback, or via an event handler. Examples:

via callback, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422945(v=vs.91).aspx

```
oContext.Load(oContext.GetUsersQuery(), operation =>
  {
    var users = operation.Entities; // here you are
  }, null);
```

via event handler, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff422589(v=VS.91).aspx

```
var operation = oContext.Load(oContext.GetUsersQuery());
operation.Completed += (s, e) =>
  {
    var users = operation.Entities; // your users are here
  };
```

I would recommend the first way.

The `DataGrid` works without it because it binds to an entityset which implements `INotifyCollectionChanged`, i.e. notifies subscribers when an entity is added to or removed from the entityset. The `DataGrid` (in fact, the `ItemsControl`) subscribes to the `INotifyCollectionChanged.CollectionChanged` event to track the entityset modifications.